# OnChange event.target.value doesnt get the value in react

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, onchange, react-radio-buttons

So I got 2 radio buttons and when they make a change i wanna get the value from the radio button that made the change.

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
handleValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      chargetype: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  <RadioGroup onChange={this.handleValue} horizontal>
            <RadioButton value="fixed">Fixed</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton value="people" >People</RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

But for some reason it doesnt get the value of the RadioButton.

Does anyone know how to do it correctly?

Comment: What are `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton`? Where are they imported from?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` event on the `RadioGroup` gives you the value directly and not the event

You can write it like

```
handleValue = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      chargetype: value,
    });
  };

  <RadioGroup onChange={this.handleValue} horizontal>
            <RadioButton value="fixed">Fixed</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton value="people" >People</RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

Above inference is based on the [`library's official example`](https://github.com/mu29/react-radio-buttons/blob/master/example/example.jsx)

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-grass-n3wzc?file=/src/App.js)